# Ogre_tools installation issues on Snow Leopard (with ROS diamondback)

Tags: ros, installation, macos-snowleopard, osx, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to build ogre_tools using the source present in ROS Diamondback on a 64bit Mac SnowLeopard. I have successfully installed Ogre (after fetching the latest version from their repo) and have placed the Ogre.framework where the ogre_tools build process looks for it. However, I am stuck with this error now,

..... Some output from the make command....
make -f CMakeFiles/python_ogre_tools.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/python_ogre_tools.dir/depend
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/sagnikdhar/ros/visualization_common/ogre_tools/CMakeFiles 20
[ 94%] Generating src/ogre_tools/ogre_tools_swig_generated.cpp, lib/ogre_tools.py
/opt/local/bin -c++ -Wall -python -modern -new_repr -keyword -fastdispatch -fvirtual -fastinit -fastunpack -I/opt/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/opt/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -o /Users/sagnikdhar/ros/visualization_common/ogre_tools/src/ogre_tools/ogre_tools_swig_generated.cpp -outdir ../lib -module ogre_tools /Users/sagnikdhar/ros/visualization_common/ogre_tools/src/ogre_tools/ogre_tools.i

make[2]: /opt/local/bin: Permission denied

make[2]: *** [src/ogre_tools/ogre_tools_swig_generated.cpp] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/python_ogre_tools.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Any idea what is going wrong ?

I found a discussion thread which discusses a similar problem, however the solution points to a ticket (Ticket ID 818) on the WillowGarage site, but the link seems broken. Any idea how I could track an older ticket on the Willow Garage site ?

Thanks a lot !

~ Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9189/ogre_tools-installation-issues-on-snow-leopard-(with-ros-diamondback)/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Thanks for the link to the ticket. However it does not solve my problem completely. From what I understand, ogre_tools_swig_generated.cpp is generated from ogre_tools.py by using swig. But this is failing. When I try to execute the command manually, this is the error that I get ,

"Unable to open file ../lib/ogre_tools.py: No such file or directory"

Does anyone know what could possibly be going wrong ?

Thanks,
Sagnik

---

Originally posted by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) with karma: 184 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on 2011-06-23**:
We faced a bunch of other issues on using ROS on a mac and decided to move to Ubuntu. So I haven't had a chance to verify if this problem has been fixed.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-17**:
Is this still an issue? How have things progressed?